# How to select date from datepicker in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a date picker html look like the following:

```html
 <tr>
<td class="day">12</td>
<td class="day">13</td>
<td class="day">14</td>
<td class="day">15</td>
<td class="day">16</td>
<td class="day">17</td>
<td class="day">18</td>
</tr>
```

I need to select any date from a date picker using selenium c#

I try to do it as this code but it fail

```
         IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='sandbox-
                 container1']/div/input"));

        table.Click();

        IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]"));

        List<IWebElement> rowEl = new List<IWebElement>(el.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

        List<IWebElement> colEl = new List<IWebElement>(el.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));

                foreach (IWebElement cols in colEl)
                       {
                      if (cols.Text.Equals("5"))          
            cols.Click();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a date-picker you should just be able to use an xpath like the below and click on it. Been a while since I have done one and I do not recall if I had to switch to the active window. You could also do a function to grab today's date + 2 and choose a date two days in advance on the date-picker.

```
//td[contains(text(), '14')]
```

or

```
 //td[text = '14']
```

Comment: Thanks ,it work fine if i have only this test case ,when I try to run in project for more than one test case it fail

Comment: Need a little bit more than "it fails". What is the error and what is happening?

Comment: date picker open but the date not selected and this is the Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible

Comment: Thanks alot , I try until the test pass by add @class to the xpath it look like this                                                                                   
//td[@class='day'and contains(text(), '14')]